# Get step step url in url string of PHP

Tags: php

Lets say i have url like this

```
$a= "http://zz.com/1/2/3/4/5/6/7";
```

say that url can have many step like 1 ,2 ,3 say something it have up to 3 or sometime up to 7

I want to get url like this from $a

```
$b="http://zz.com/";
$c="http://zz.com/1/";
$d="http://zz.com/1/2/";
$e="http://zz.com/1/2/3/";
...
...
$k= "http://zz.com/1/2/3/4/5/6/;
```

Is it possible to do such things in php?

Thank you very much .

I tried to use php url parse and explode but get empty value in beginning and end of array.

Comment: You can use .htaccess and set url values as parameters

Comment: using .htacess just for 1 time use is not good isn't it?

Comment: use the explode function... works like a charm... see my answer below

Comment: @Lance : you are right that it works charm but .htaccess is more fast than the function.

Comment: it is better to show what you have tried so we can help you from there

Comment: @NaveedRamzan how does one access those .htaccess values within PHP without changing the URL?

Comment: @Andrew yes i would show my work if i had idea. One cannot show without knowing idea.

Comment: As @Stlawrance said that he want to get parameters from URL. 

So we can write rules in .htaccess

    RewriteRule ^http://www.zz.com/1/2 filename.php?param1=$1&param2=$2
    RewriteRule ^http://www.zz.com/1 filename.php?param1=$1

and so on.

Comment: @stlawrance is my example not correct?  Or do you need variables named as letters to make it correct?

Comment: @NaveedRamzan the issue with that approach is that the URL is altered prior to PHP processing, and thus is truly breaking the original incoming query string prior to php seeing it.  Just doesn't make sense when the URL is available in PHP and can be safely processed independent of anything else passed in the query string.

Comment: your post did not show any effort of research nor any codes attempt on trying, just saying

Comment: By the way i think using .htacess just for 1 page for 1 function  is not good isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple way is to use explode() function.

[EDIT] made it use letters as variables if that was necessary

```
$a= "http://zz.com/14/2/13/4/5/8/7";

//grab the protocol and addy
$x = explode('//',$a);
$y = explode('/',$x[1]);

$letters = array();

$letters[1] = 'a';
$letters[2] = 'b';
$letters[3] = 'c';
$letters[4] = 'd';
$letters[5] = 'e';
$letters[6] = 'f';
$letters[7] = 'g';
$letters[8] = 'h';
$letters[9] = 'i';
$letters[10] = 'j';


//loop through various steps
for($i = 1; $i<=count($y); $i++)
{
  $$letters[$i] = $x[0].'//'.$y[0].'/';
  for($k=0; $k<$i; $k++)
  {
    $$letters[$i] .= $y[$k].'/';
  }
}

echo $a."\n";
echo $b."\n";
echo $c."\n";
echo $d."\n";
echo $e."\n";
echo $f."\n";
echo $g."\n";
echo $h."\n";
```

that will output:

```
http://zz.com/zz.com/
http://zz.com/zz.com/14/
http://zz.com/zz.com/14/2/
http://zz.com/zz.com/14/2/13/
http://zz.com/zz.com/14/2/13/4/
http://zz.com/zz.com/14/2/13/4/5/
http://zz.com/zz.com/14/2/13/4/5/8/
http://zz.com/zz.com/14/2/13/4/5/8/7/
```

You can see the code working here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c0446acaf0fd298fc089b743da5a807529e3e0b
[EDIT: with letters here]http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb655992fa81f0005938d86697e91272dc57425a

Comment: Yes this is what actually i want. I just modified post because people were think the number are in ascending order.

Comment: I edited it to show both that the numbers are not sequential and that you "could" use letter variables if you wanted.  If this works for you, please mark it as the answer.  Cheers

Comment: Thanks for you work and research :) . I also like this method than editing .htacess.

Comment: There are so many reasons not to use the .htaccess file.  It simply is not portable or stable to use the .htaccess

Comment: `$letters = range('a', 'j');` try it

Comment: Thanks Robert... I've been using PHP since v2 and haven't once used range, yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:-

```
<?php
$a= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];//"http://zz.com/1/2/3";
$url = explode('/',str_replace('http://', '', $a));

$next_num = count($url);

echo $next_url = $a.'/'.$next_num;//wil print :- http://zz.com/1/2/3/4

?>
```

Comment: you mean /4 can come before /1. what do you want the next url after the url in comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can and it is pretty easy and it is good to use build in function called [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) which extracts some parts of URL.

```
$url = "http://zz.com/1/2/3/4/5/6/7";

$pathvars = parse_url($url);
$urls = [];
$glue = '';
$counter = 'a';
foreach ($path as $part) {
    $glue .= "$part/";
    $urls[$counter++] = sprintf("%s://%s%s", $pathvars['scheme'], substr($pathvars['host'], 0, strlen($pathvars['host']) -1), substr($glue, 0, strlen($glue) - 1));
}

// extract to variables
extract($urls, EXTR_OVERWRITE);

echo $a . PHP_EOL;
echo $b . PHP_EOL;
echo $c . PHP_EOL; 
echo $d . PHP_EOL; // etc
print_r($urls); // all array of urls
```

Comment: That only gets each step, but not each incremental step